# Create multiple input files using a run matrix

Tags: r, apply

I have a list of runs with weights for variables (V1, V2, V5) that I am trying to apply to my input file and then print the input file to a text document. It seems like this would be a good use for the apply function, but I don't have experience doing matrix multiplication with a subset of a data.frame and then putting that function in the apply function.

```
# A list of runs with weights for 3 variables
run_table <- expand.grid(V1 = seq(0.5, 1.5, 0.5), V2 = seq(0.5, 1.5, 0.5), V5 = c(0,1))

# My input file (my input file has more columns and variables than this)
text1 <- c('various', 'text', 'values', 'for', 'input', 'files', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
num <- c(4, 2, 2, 8, 16, 2, 8, 24, 8, 2)
name <- c('V1', 'V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V4', 'V5', 'V5', 'V6')

input_file <- data.frame(text1, num, name)

# For each row in the run_table multiply the weight for variables V1, V2, & V5 by the value in input_file$num, then print the table to a text file

# Pseudo-code
for i to nrows(run_table)
run_table[i,]*input_file
write.table(input, file = paste0("input_", i, ".dat"), sep = " ", quote = F, row.names = F, col.names = F)
```

Comment: It's a common assumption that `apply` cures all ills, and though it can be shoe-horned into some scenarios, it doesn't *need* to be used for this, nor does it really add anything. I suggest you just use `for (i in seq_len(nrow(run_table))) { ... ; write.table(...); }`. You will have no performance issues that `apply` would solve.

Comment: @Erin input_file$num column has 10 values  and the third column has names V1, V2, V3, V4, V5. How do you want the input_file$num values be multiplied by the values in 3x18 matrix run_table?